# Mysql LEFT JOIN not returing expected result

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create LEFT JOIN using following 4 tables.
The idea is to display the parent.name for the userid's.Should groupconcat the childnames,if the user is not in the child users table the child.name should be NULL

Following is the expected result for user id 1:

```
  id     parentname    childname
-------------------------------------------------
  1        parent1      child1,child3
```

Following is the expected result for user id 2:
This user is not there in the childusers table, so it should return null

```
  id     parentname    childname
-------------------------------------------------
  1        parent2      NULL
```

Tables:

parent

```
 id        parentname
--------------------------------------------
  1        parent1
  2        parent2
  3        parent3
```

child

```
  id        childname     parent_id
-----------------------------------------------
  1         child1       1
  2         child2       2
  3         child3       1
```

parentusers

```
  id        parent_id    user_id
-------------------------------------------------------
  1            1           1
  2            2           2
  3            3           1
```

childusers

```
  id        child_id    user_id
-------------------------------------------------------
  1            1           1
```

Here is my query:

```
 SELECT parent.name AS parentname,
 GROUP_CONCAT(child.name SEPARATOR ',') AS childname
 FROM parentusers,parent
 LEFT JOIN child
 ON parent.id=child.parent_id
 WHERE parentusers.parent_id= parent.id
 AND parentusers.user_id='1'
 GROUP BY parent.id
```

I have written two seperate queries but want to combine these two in single result in the above mentioned result format.

```
 select parent.parentname from parent,parentusers
 where parent.id=parentusers.parent_id
 and parentusers.user_id=1 ;

 select GROUP_CONCAT(child.childname) as childname from child
 LEFT JOIN childusers
 ON child.id=childusers.child_id
 where childusers.user_id=1;
```

Thanks..

Comment: Could we get an sqlfiddle for this?

Comment: here is the fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ffaa/3

Comment: please check it and help me

Comment: updated fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ffaa/13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the expected result from the following query

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT parent.parentname AS parentname, 
parent.id AS parentid 
FROM parent,parentusers
WHERE parent.id=parentusers.parent_id
AND parentusers.user_id='2') parentdata
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(child.childname SEPARATOR ',') AS childname,
GROUP_CONCAT(child.id SEPARATOR ',') AS childid
FROM parent

LEFT JOIN parentusers
ON parent.id=parentusers.parent_id

LEFT JOIN child
ON child.parent_id=parent.id
AND child.parent_id=parentusers.parent_id

LEFT JOIN childusers
ON child.id=childusers.child_id

AND childusers.user_id=parentusers.user_id
WHERE childusers.user_id='2' 
GROUP BY parent.id ) childdata
ON parentdata.parentid=childdata.childid
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ffaa/50

Answer (score 0):

I see the following errors in your query:

1. There is a syntax error (extra comma) bofore `FROM` clause.
2. You give alias name for table `child` as `sub` and then you are trying to join with `child.parent_id`.

Try this:

```
SELECT parent.name AS parentname, IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(child.name),'') AS childname
FROM parentusers LEFT JOIN 
     parent ON parentusers.parent_id=parent.id LEFT JOIN 
     child sub ON parent.id=sub.parent_id
WHERE parentusers.user_id='1'
GROUP BY parent.id
```

Modifications I made (except the error correction):

1. Used a `LEFT JOIN` to join tables `parentusers` and `parent`.
2. Added `IFNULL` which will return an empty string if `GROUP_CONCAT` is null.

Comment: in your query parent table is not used, but parent.id is there in the join

Comment: i tried your query, for user 2 child. name is not giving null

Comment: @user1851420: Doesn't it give an empty string?

Comment: it's not giving empty if user not exists in the childusers table, also in your query there is no joins with childusers table

Comment: @user1851420: See [**this fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ffaa/23). You search for userid=2. Then how it will select others? For the next doubt, you don't use `childuser` in your query in question, right?

Comment: it's simple it should return the parent i have joined and also the child i have joined (child names with group concat) and if there is no child entry for me it should return null, this is the rquirement.

Comment: @user1851420: My answer will get you the required result you shown in the question if you remove the `where` clause. If that is not the required result, please edit your question.

Comment: in your fiddle for user id 2 it's returning child name as child2, but it should return null

Comment: i have created two seperate queries, but want to combine those two, please see my edit

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51526/discussion-between-raging-bull-and-user1851420)

Comment: @user1851420: Can you show the results of each queries?

Comment: @user1851420: Then post it as an answer.